# Codeigniter AES decode showing strange chars

Tags: codeigniter, aes, decode, encode

i tryed:

```
$data = array('ip'=>'120.0.3.4','user'=>'robert');

 $this->load->library('encrypt');
    $this->encrypt->set_cipher(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256);
    $this->encrypt->set_mode(MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $key = random_string();
    $o=$this->encrypt->encode($data,$key);
var_dump($o);
$this->encrypt->set_cipher(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256);
    $this->encrypt->set_mode(MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $o = $this->encrypt->decode($o,$key);
    var_dump($o);
```

it retunrs strange chars in decoding:

```
string(44) "CVwMzZGkzagW4wHbUZfNpVWACQp2Fx4TeAO2KLqZs3I=" string(32) "��pz��xJx�jʊ8�Kw��mS�Y �1�_�"
```

any suggestion?

is this caused from the array encryption? i need to encrypt value by value instead of encrypt all the array to use the array of encrypted data??
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an array into `$this->encrypt->encode()`. The `encode()` method takes a string. See [Encryption Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html).

If you had PHP errors enabled you would also see:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: mcrypt_encrypt() expects parameter 3 to be string, array given
Filename: libraries/Encrypt.php
```

[Turn PHP errors on](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on your development machine to catch these.